# What's the meaning of '@' in a DNS zone file?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have the following data in my DNS zone file for my domain:

```
$ORIGIN mydomain.com.
@       IN      A       208.X.Y.Z
mail    IN      A       208.X.Y.Z
... etc..
```

What does the `@` line mean? I know what an A record is.. but a host with an <strike>ampersand</strike> [at sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/@)?

Comment: A little nitpicky perhaps but @ is not an ampersand. ;)

Comment: HAHAH oooops :) That's so true .... time to fix that up.. (donno why i said it's an ampersand / & ) .. ....

Comment: @ is not an ampersand, but 85,000 people have arrived here across 9 years because they made the same mistake. =) So thanks for this accident, I was one of those people.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

[RFC 1035](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035) defines the format of a DNS zone file.

... on [page 35](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1035#page-35) you'll find:

> @               A free standing @ is
> used to denote the current origin.

This means that `@` is a shortcut for the name defined with `$ORIGIN`.

You can find more information on `$ORIGIN` [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/879913/dns-origin-dot), which is an excerpt from *Pro DNS and BIND*, published by Apress.

Comment: So what does `mydomain.com.  IN   A   208.X.Y.Z` mean?

Answer (score 73):

It's the root, or in your example it's mydomain.com.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be equivalent when I try it out. I made an `A` record for `mydomain.com.` pointing to my host's IP. This makes a DNS lookup fail with the error that it couldn't resolve the hostname. If I change the `mydomain.com.` to `@`, the domain resolves and my website becomes reachable. What is the difference between the two? I assume the zone isn't `mydomain.com`? (I'm setting these records in the Namecheap control panel).

Comment: @DanielSaner The part to put before the IN is the prefix before mydomain.com. So if you put mydomain.com, that really means mydomain.com.mydomain.com. So that's why the @ is an important character which translates simple to mydomain.com.

Comment: My understanding was that the trailing `.` designates the name as fully qualified, so the origin shouldn't be appended. That would be according to RFC 1535, and it's in fact the way my registrar uses it in their examples: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9256/29/how-to-edit-dns-zone-in-cpanel
But such a configuration doesn't work when I try it. Maybe the control panel does something else than just add the information to the zone as-is?

Comment: Yeah, much of that is up to the implementation of the DNS tool. You'll see the @ when you work with the DNS files directly, but you'll rarely see it in the various DNS tools. The DNS tools try to simplify the UI. From your messages it sounds like you have it working one way but not another so I recommend going with the way that it does work. DNS tools are really up to the implementation of the tool, and even DNS servers may not implement this the same way according to specs.

Comment: So to summarise, for a properly working DNS server, `@` and `domain.com.` should be equivalent?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai That's entirely up to the DNS server how it's implemented (whether or not it supports entering domain.com, or @), but in concept you're exactly right.

Answer (score 7):

It's an alias for the zone name itself.  In this case, it indicates that the zone name has that address (or mx record, or ...)