# MX records not working on Amazon route 53

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, mx-record, amazon-route53

I have configured my Amazon route 53 DNS to add the google apps MX records and here is how my route 53 configuration looks like (please ignore the upper red box in the photo) :

[image]
However, these MX records do not reflect when I use the mxtoolbox.com debug tool shown below :

[image]
Please help. I would like to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: You may just need to wait for the previous values to expire.  Give it some more time then try again.

Comment: Did this issue ever get resolved?

Answer (score 4):

You've added the records for a subdomain `@.example.com` instead of just plain `example.com`. While the use of `@` to represent the root is a [common syntax](https://serverfault.com/questions/83874/whats-the-meaning-of-in-a-dns-zone-file) in some DNS tools, it's not supported in Route53.

Adding the records with an empty `Name` field will place the records on the root of the domain.