# When trying to fix MX records for email forwarding in godaddy wizard appears not to be working

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, godaddy

I have migrated my domain from godaddy.com to Amazon and it works fine. But when I try to use the email forwarding in godaddy an error appears with a wizard and a solution:

[image: error]

When clicking save a confirmation screen appears:

[image]

but when clicking "continue" the page does not respond. Is this only a UI problem? will the problem with the MX records be solved in 48 hours? Is there another way of editing MX records? can godaddy work for mail while a the same time Amazon for hosting?

Comment: When you say "migrated your domain to Amazon" please be more precise. Have you changed your DNS A records? Do you have MX records? This seems like a support problem for GoDaddy, not a technology problem. You can easily use one service for web hosting (A records) and another for email (MX records) - it's very common, I do it myself. You need to tell us your domain name if you want any real help, so we can look at the records directly.

Comment: Technologically there is nothign stopping you from serving HTTP/S via Amazon and having your SMTP being handled by godaddy - it is as simple as having the lowest priority number (therefore highest priority) MX record for your domain pointing to some godaddy server and A records for example.com and www.example.com pointing to an IP at Amazon/etc.  Who do you have your domain registered with? Who is handling your DNS ?

Comment: @Tim, by migrating I mean I changed the name servers and I'am hosting http://peaku.co on Amazon. On godaddy no MX records appear. Thanks

Comment: @ivanian I have the domain registered with Godaddy and Amazon is handling the DNS, thanks.

Comment: Go Daddy can't reconfigure your MX records.  If your DNS is in a hosted zone in Route 53, **you** need to configure the correct MX records **in Route 53**.  It's not clear what they are asking your permission to even do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DNS is hosted on AWS Route 53. You need to add MX entries to your Route53 hosted zone. Some documentation is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/rrsets-working-with.html).

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/434746/mx-records-not-working-on-amazon-route-53) gives a useful screenshot that you may find helpful.