# Azure AD connect DNS verification error

Tags: azure, entra-id

I am trying to setup the Azure AD connect in the new portal. For days, when I tried to add a domain, it gave me the "Forbidden" error. I thought it was some bug in the new portal because in the old portal it worked fine. Now after a few days, it does indeed suddenly work.

But now I cannot verify my domain by txt or mx record. This is the error:

> Unable to verify domain name. Ensure you have added the record above
>   at the registrar 'domainname.com', and try again in a little while.

With mxtoolbox, "dig" on Linux and "NSLOOKUP" on Windows, it all shows the right records on different locations. 
The domain is not verified in any other directory and I have waited for hours now so the record is wordwide published.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question.

Here is a similar [issue](http://gerryhampsoncm.blogspot.sg/2015/03/could-not-verify-domain-in-azure.html) about unable to verify domain name. It explained that the @ does not always work for TXT record even through you can save it without seeing any errors. So the blogger left the Hostname blank and could verify the domain.
Hope this helps you.

If you still have questions, welcome to post back here. Thanks.

Comment: Well, basically the @ is the root domainname as explained here: http://serverfault.com/questions/83874/whats-the-meaning-of-in-a-dns-zone-file/83877#83877
So I didn't even try it with the @ in the hostname.. and still not working. But thanks for your answer of course