# What does @ mean in a hostname in DNS configuration?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016

I'm creating new DNS records in our DC (Windows Server 2016) and I bump into zones where there are a lot of records that do not have a regular hostname, only an "@".

We are using scopes and policies, new Windows Server 2016 features for DNS configuration.

I know that one can use "*" for wildcards in hostnames, but I don't know the meaning of "@".

[image: Hostnames with "@"]

Comment: "registers"?  Is that a valid term or would entries or records be better?  We're talking about resource records (RRs)...

Comment: @MatthewElvey I think you are right, entries or records sounds better than "registers".

Comment: also see https://serverfault.com/q/83874

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If the name for a domain (or *zone*) is "example.com.", then an @ record indicates that the name for the DNS record is also "example.com."

In the GUI for a Microsoft Windows Server DNS Service, this is (or at least has been for a long time) called "Same as parent folder".

Normally the name used for a DNS record indicates everything before the name of the zone (commonly called the "domain name"). So if you enter a record named "server01" in a DNS zone called "example.com.", then the full record is "server01.example.com." If you want to enter a record where the full record is just "example.com" (which is necessary for a lot of things, like MX records), then you enter an @ in many DNS systems to tell the DNS server to respond to requests for "example.com." with the data you add to the record in question.

Comment: The `example.com` is actually shortened `example.com.` – in DNS server configuration `example.com` becomes `example.com.example.com.`, because without the tailing dot it's relative to the `$ORIGIN`, which could be referred with the `@`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now I understand better how it works.

Answer (score 21):

For what I could find in the RFC, it stands for

```
@               A free standing @ is used to denote the current origin.
```

Source: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035

Hope it helps